# nested CPS "reset"

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, continuations, continuation-passing, delimited-continuations

using the CPS compiler-plugin of Scala 2.8, there are the two magic controls `reset` and `shift`. Reset delimits the continuation and shift captures the continuation.

There is an [example](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2096#comment-7674) of using CPS with NIO, using nested resets as a type of "forking"...?
I don't exactly understand the purpose of nesting the resets, what's the effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing magic about nested a `reset`.  A `shift` applies to the innermost `reset` that encloses it.  The pseudo-forking comment you see is just a description of the effective behavior from the callbacks registered with the NIO selector.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I still do not fully understand why the read/write handlers need a different continuation-delimitation and the primary reset() for accepting the connections won't suffice.